# Forward port to OpenVpn client with static IP

Tags: openvpn, port-forwarding, static-ip, asus

I have running OpenVpn server on my router Asus RT-AC58U. The router has public static IP 82.119.97.206
On the OpenVpn server I have setup two clients with static ip:

- 10.8.0.10 - my laptop (Ubuntu 19.10)
- 10.8.0.8 - my server (plain Ubuntu 18.04 with few apps installed)

Both are running applications on port 8080

When I'm connected to vpn(for example with the laptop 10.8.0.10) I can access both with `telnet 10.8.0.8 8080` or `telnet 10.8.0.10 8080` and I get connection.

When I setup port forwarding from router's `:80` to `10.8.0.10:8080` using router ui, everything is fine and I get response accesing router's public IP (82.119.97.206), but changing the IP to my server's `:80` to `10.8.0.8:8080` I'm getting timeout.

To access I use phone going to 82.119.97.206, but also laptop without vpn using different network.
My local net is 192.168.1.1/24
My vpn net is 10.8.0.1/24

What could cause this, how should I debug it?

Comment: This is a little bit confusing. Please clarify what is your local IP net, what is your OpvenVPN net, what computer is 10.0.0.8 (did you switch the last number for your VPN and local net, that is 10.8.0.8 becomes 10.0.0.10?), from what computer can't you access port 8080 on the server and what route is that connection taking.

Comment: I have updated the description a bit, sorry for the few mistakes. I hope now it is more understandable. Please ask for details if you need, I am not an expert, just have som linux and networking knowledge.

Comment: There can be a lot of things going wrong here, so basically we would need to see your OpenVPN config, your NAT config and your firewall config both on the router and server. Though I think the simplest solution would be to port forward to the local net address (192.168.1.x) of the server, not go through the VPN with the port forwarding.